# wp_get_current_user does not work properly on log in page

Tags: login

**Desired Outcome**

I am developing a plugin that should redirect the user away from log in page if they are already logged in.

So if anyone goes to example.com/wp-login.php and they are already logged in, the redirect should kick in.

**Current Progress**

I am using `login_init` hook to determine that we are in the log in page and `wp_get_current_user()` to get the user.

```php
function redirect_logged_in_users() {
   if (is_user_logged_in()) {
     wp_redirect($destination);
  }
}

add_action('login_init', 'redirect_logged_in_users');
```

**The Problem**

This works well in any other page using some other hook, like `init`, but whenever I try this with `login_init` the `wp_get_current_user()` returns an empty user as if no one is logged in.

I know that there's a user logged in.

**Additional Context**

I am not a WordPress dev and I am almost sure that I am doing something in a non-WordPress way. Happy to take any other approach which helps to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You have a chicken and egg problem going.  login_init is called PRIOR to the user actually logged in. It just indicates with the login page has been displayed. 
(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/)

The hook should be:  wp_login.  This fires after a user has successfully logged-in.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/

```
add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_logged_in_users');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just tried it. It seems that "wp_login" fires only after the user has logged in by entering username and password.

However, in my case, I need to know if they are authenticated (or logged in) before the log in page loads.